# Nodejs MongoError: auth fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an user(username:hxh,password:1234) in my local mongodb,when I execute :

```
hxh@ubuntu:~/share/nodejs/appid2zgk7rv83v$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
connecting to: test
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.auth('hxh','1234')
1
>
```

This shows that my username and password is OK,but when I try to connect the mongodb in my nodejs app:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;  
var db = new Db('test', new Server('localhost', '27017')); 
db.open(function(err, db) {
  db.authenticate('hxh', '1234', function(err, result) { 
    .....
  });  
});
```

I got the error

```
MongoError: auth fails
```

So why I got this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should pass your dbname i.e. 'admin' instead if 'test'

```
var db = new Db('admin', new Server('localhost', '27017'));
```

Comment: thanks,this works,but I just want to connect the `test` database,not `admin` what should I do?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-connect-node-js-to-a-mongodb-database-on-a-vpsThis may help you to connect to test database:

Comment: I know,just  `var secondDb = db.db("test");`

Answer (score 1):

try to create the user and pass in the test table:
use test;
db.createUser...